# Facebook Check if user "Liked" the page

Tags: facebook, canvas

I made a few Facebook `FBML` Canvas pages (Facebook considers these to be Applications) for a company, and they requested that users who "Like" the page would be redirected to another page, or the page will display different content with AJAX.

I went through the Facebook Developers Documentation, but I can't find a clue on how to do it.

I'm sure someone has done it before, any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the Facebook forum I think it might help you out!

[How can i redirect when someone like/share?](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=252358)

I haven't tried it myself though!

Good luck!

Comment: @harsh this is the best I can do http://web.archive.org/web/20110819203920/http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=252358

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the JS or PHP sdk to check if a user liked a page. See examples below...

Uses JS sdk to check if a user liked a page (can be any page, just set the page id). This can be used in a standalone app or from within a page tab. - http://unbound-media.com/facebook/how-to-tell-if-a-facebook-user-likes-your-facebook-application/

Uses PHP sdk to check if a user liked the page from a tabbed app (can only check if user liked the current page they're on). This method can also be converted to JS. - [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with facebook app tab page, the following code helps you to find `isfan` status

```js
$signed = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 'YOUR-APP-SECRET');
if ($signed['page']['liked'] == 1) {
    $fan = true;
} else {
    $fan = false;
}
```

Visit [this link](http://jobyj.in/api/check-user-is-fan-of-facebook-page/) for demo and source code.