# How to check user like the facebook Application or not?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page

How can we check user liked the facebook application or not?

I am trying to create a Facebook app, in it there are two different pages , if user liked then  page_1 will be show, otherwise page_2 show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php 
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
if ($user) { 

try{ 
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
 $likeID = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query',
 'query' => 'SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = "'.$user_profile['id'].'" AND url="myurl/"'; )); 
}
 catch(FacebookApiException $e) { }
 } 
if(count($likeID)>0) echo "User likes this page"; 
else echo "User doesn\'t like this page";

?>
```

## credible and/or official sources:

1. http://www.zuberi.me/2011/how-to-check-if-user-liked-the-application-or-page.html
2. http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php
3. [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page)
4. [Facebook how to check if user has liked page and show content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content)
5. [Facebook Check if user "Liked" the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750012/facebook-check-if-user-liked-the-page)

Comment: <?php 
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
if ($user) {
 try{ 
       $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
       $likeID = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = "'.$user_profile['id'].'" AND url="http://myurl/"' )); 
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e)
{

}
}
 if(count($likeID)>0)
 echo "User likes this page";
 else
 echo "User doesn\'t like this page"; ?>

Comment: You can also update my answer. If you feels it should will be better for other users. And then on you also can accept answer, if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to the problem can be:

```
// to generate user access token after the user is logged in
$USER_ACCESS_TOKEN = $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();

$isFan = curl("https://api.facebook.com/method/pages.isFan?format=json&access_token=" . $USER_ACCESS_TOKEN . "&page_id=" . $FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID);

        function curl($url) {

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "your app id";
$app_secret = "your app secret";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();


$like_status = $signed_request["app"]["liked"];


if ($like_status == 1){
echo 'User likes this page';
}
else{
echo 'User doesn\'t like this page';
}
```

Maybe you should try somethng like this, check [Facebook's PHP SDK reference page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) for the exact approach.

Comment: `<?php
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
 try{
 $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
 $likeID = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 
      'query' => 'SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = "'.$user_profile['id'].'" AND url="http://myurl/"'
    ));
 }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
 }
}
if(count($likeID)>0)
echo "User likes this page";
else
echo "User doesn\'t like this page";
?>`

Did it by above method

Comment: Hi Frank, I dont know php. Can you convert it javascript or asp.net for me?